# UISearchController with UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have add UISearchBar to UITableView. I have bug (IOS 12). UISearchBar is jumping after I dismiss it. I have attach a video. In my case I need adding searchBar to tableView (`navigationItem.searchController = searchController` is not solution)
[Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gskxu8ifipx1m3i/Untitled.mov?dl=0)

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Comment: Have u try on real device ?

Comment: It’s jumps with iOS 11 SDK or later. Therefore you should use as a `navigationItem.searchController = searchController`.

Comment: what you  want to achieve rather than  jumping